# How can i loop over same list again with an conditional increment count

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying for a roaster method, where I have want to loop over
the same list and print primary,secondary and change the primary and secondary every week,if weekday is monday.

```
team = [('abc', 123),('def', 343),('ghi', 345),('jkl', 453)]
```

Week 1:- 
primary :- ('abc', 123)
secondary :- ('def', 343)

Week 2:-
primary:- ('ghi', 345)
secondary:- ('jkl', 453)

Week 3:-
primary:- ('jkl', 453)
secondary:-('abc', 123)

And so on.

```
team = [('abc', 123),('def', 343),('ghi', 345),('jkl', 453)]
count = 0
if week_day == 'Wed':
    if True:
        count += 1
print('count', count)
print('pri', team[count][0])
print('sec_name', team[count + 1])
```

Comment: you need a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can use generators/. With [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) you can iterate over a list indefinitely:

```
import itertools as it

team = [('abc', 123), ('def', 343), ('ghi', 345), ('jkl', 453)]

pri_gen = it.cycle(team)
sec_gen = it.cycle(team)
next(sec_gen) # remove the first abc and start with def

for pri, sec in zip(pri_gen, sec_gen):
    print(pri, sec)
    # wait until next monday
```

Comment: For loop is continuously printing the pri,sec.I need only one for the week and next week the second one

Comment: @vinaykn then you'll have to use a database or some other way to store the state. Your program probably won't run indefinitely with one week sleep.